# Subclassing a UIView subclass loaded from a nib

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class, `FooView`, that is a subclass of `UIView`, and whose view is loaded from a nib, something like:

```
+ (instancetype)viewFromNib
{
    NSArray *xib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FooView" owner:self options:nil];
    return [xib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

The nib itself has its Custom Class set to `FooView` in the Identity Inspector.

This is instantiated as:

```
FooView *view = [FooView viewFromNib];
```

This behaves as you'd expect. However, when FooView is itself subclassed as FooSubclassView, and instantiated as:

```
FooSubclassView *view = [FooSubclassView viewFromNib];
```

`view` is still of type `FooView`, not `FooSubclassView`.

Swizzling the class with `object_setClass` doesn't fix the fact that the underlying object is an instance of `FooView`, and thus methods called on the subclass instance will be those of the superclass (`FooView`), not `FooSubclassView`.

How can I correct this so that subclasses are of the correct type, without having to create a new nib for every subclass, or having to reimplement `viewFromNib` in every subclass?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swizzling is not (ever) the answer.

The problem is in your NIB;  it is archived with object[0] being an instance of `FooView`, not `FooSubclassView`.   If you want to load the *same* NIB with a *different* view subclass as object[0], you need to move the instance out of the NIB's archive.

Probably the easiest thing to do, since your class is already loading the NIB, is make an instance of `FooView` or `FooSubclassView` the *File's Owner*.

This question has a decent explanation of the *File's Owner* pattern.  Note that you are pretty much already there in that your class is what is loading the XIB/NIB anyway.

And here is the official [docs on File's Owner](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW15).

Comment: I'm not exactly getting this. If the view is the File Owner, then you need another class which will be the visual "canvas" that you draw on using IB, right? Sorry if this question isn't that clear, but I've got a NIB with just a single NSView subclass in it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you are onto the best solution, but I think this is what you are looking for.

```
+ (instancetype)viewFromNib
{
    NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
    NSArray *xib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:className owner:self options:nil];
    return [xib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

That is as long as you can be sure that the NIB has the same name as the class.

---

After realizing that I mistook one of the requirements, I say I'll have to agree with @bbum.

```
- (id)init
{
    // NOTE: If you don't know the size, you can work this out after you load the nib.
    self = [super initWithFrame:GCRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    if (self) {
        // Load the nib using the instance as the owner.
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FooView" owner:self options:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (instancetype)viewFromNib
{
    return [[self alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: That won't work;  you are loading the NIB with the name `className`, which means you'll need one NIB per class.   At least, I don't think that is what OP wants.   But maybe it is...

Comment: Well darn, I didn't notice that requirement.